# Как собрать все значения массивов у классов зависимостей?

Tags: php, наследование, рефлексия, assets

Реализуется механизм зависимостей. Есть класс `Asset`, в котором есть свойство `css` (далее будут еще свойства), `isConnected` и `depends`. От этого класса создаются (расширяют `extends`) другие классы assets (примеры ниже).

```
class Asset {
   public $js = [];
   public $depends = [];

   public function connect() {...}
}
```

Мне необходимо реализовать логику:

1. Собираются все классы по зависимостям в какую-то переменную главного класса;
2. При вызове метода `connect` у главного класса произвести какое-то действие (будет генерация html кода), но так, чтобы он учитывал уже подключенные классы.

Проще говоря, создаю я `JqueryAssets`, `UiAssets`, `BootboxAssets`.

```
class JqueryAssets extends Asset {
   public $js = [...]
}

class UiAssets extends Asset {
   public $js = [...]
   public $depends = ['assets\JqueryAssets']
}

class BootboxAssets extends Asset {
   public $js = [...]
   public $depends = ['assets\JqueryAssets']
}
```

И вот я на странице `index.php` хочу в `<head>` инициализировать `UiAssets`, а в `<body>` - `BootboxAssets`. Так как `UiAssets` инициализируется первым, то он он подключает к своим `js` еще и `js` из `JqueryAssets`. Соответственно, `BootboxAssets` уже не должен подключать `js` из `JqueryAssets`.

Вот как реализовать такую логику?

UPD.

```php
private $dependsMap = [];
private $dependsClassMap = [];

public function getDepends() {
    $depends = $this->depends;

    foreach ($this->depends as $depend) {
        $dependReflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($depend);
        /** @var Asset $dependReflectionClassInstance */
        $dependReflectionClassInstance = $dependReflectionClass->newInstance();
        $depends = array_merge($depends, $dependReflectionClassInstance->getDepends());
    }

    return $depends;
}
```

На выходе адекватный массив:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'assets\HeaderAssets' (length=19)
  1 => string 'assets\CssAssets' (length=16)
```

Но вот как теперь получить массив формата:

```
className => Object
```

UPD.

То есть, необходимо получить массив:

```
assets\HeaderAssets => object assets\HeaderAssets...
assets\CssAssets => object assets\CssAssets
```

Это нужно для того, чтобы при подключении ассетов пройтись по каждому классу зависимости и проверить его на `isConnected`. Это проверка даст возможность не подключать css или js повторно.

Если есть другие варианты более качественной реализации, то готов выслушать их и обсудить.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вполне можете это реализовать аналогично статическому массиву карты классов в автозагрузчике - уникальный ключ в нём будет сигнализировать о классе (или ресурсе), который уже загружен (либо ему предстоит загрузка). В других словах у вас будет менеджер ресурсов, которые будет отслеживать ресурсы, загружать их и обрабатывать запросы препроцессинга.

В конструкторе вашего ресурса сделаете вызов к менеджеру ресурсов с вашим массивом, и всего-то делов.

Comment: То есть для начала надо составить карту зависимостей. Если это делается в основном классе, от которого все наследуются, то обход делать с помощью рефлексии или путем цикла с инициализацией классов?

Comment: Вполне можно обойтись и без строковых значений в depends и писать туда [JqueryAssets::class], к примеру, и использовать рефлексию для обхода.

Comment: Реализовал свойства: `private $dependsMap = []; private $dependsClassMap = [];` и метод `getDepends` (см. описание вопроса). Получилось получить массив адекватный наименований классов. А как вот получить массив объектов?

Comment: Что именно, какого типа Object вы собираетесь получить в массиве className => Object? Приведите пример, а так же пример класса JqueryAssets с namespace.

Comment: Описал в вопросе выше. namespace у всех ассетов `assets\...`, а у главного `kernel\helpers`